# Unit Testing with karma in Angular 4 with Webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, karma-jasmine

Here is my karma.config.js file -

```
module.exports = function (config) {

config.set({
basePath: '',
frameworks: ['jasmine'],

plugins: [
  require('karma-jasmine'),
  require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
  require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
  'karma-webpack',
  'karma-babel-preprocessor',
  // 'babel-preset-es2015'
],

client: {
  builtPaths: [appBase, testingBase], // add more spec base paths as needed
  clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
},

customLaunchers: {
  // From the CLI. Not used here but interesting
  // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
  Chrome_travis_ci: {
    base: 'Chrome',
    flags: ['--no-sandbox']
  }
},
mime: {
  'text/x-typescript': ['ts']
},
files: [
  './src/client/app/phone/component/nokia.component.ts',
  './src/client/app/phone/component/nokia.spec.ts'
],

// Proxied base paths for loading assets
proxies: {
  // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
  "/app/": appAssets
},
// webpack: configureWebpack(),
exclude: [],
preprocessors: {
  './src/client/app/phone/component/nokia.component.spec.ts': ['babel', 'webpack'],
},
// babelPreprocessor: {
//   options: {
//     "presets": ["es2015"]
//   }
// },
reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
port: 9876,
colors: true,
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
autoWatch: true,
browsers: ['Chrome'],
singleRun: false
});


 };

function configureWebpack() {
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');
webpackConfig.entry = undefined; // karma will pass the proper 
argument for entry
return webpackConfig;
}
```

The Problem I am facing is I can not Access component from spec file.
karma throws err-

> ERROR in ./src/client/app/phone/component/nokia.component.spec.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './nokia.component' in '/media/folder/New Volume/.....**path**'
>    @ ./src/client/app/phone/component/nokia.component.spec.ts 1:0-61

What I get -

Basically i can not Access Import statements from spec file. As Our components are using ES6 things but my karma Configuration can not understand that ES6 things.

Is their any way that can tell or convert my ES6 things to ES5 So that my browser can understand this.

On this I found this thing **'babel-preset-es2015'** but i can not fit this into my config file of karma.

Or is their any alternate way - in karma config so that i can test my all components with Karma Jasmine in Angular 4 .

NOTE - I am using webpack directly (Not angular cli).

Please answer for webpack